# Apache Camel route from ActiveMQ to HTTP service

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have ActiveMQ and HTTP rest service.
I need to read a message from the queue and send it to http service. If http code 200 - remove the message from the queue. It could be done by custom service/daemon.

I have an idea to solve it with Apache Camel. Is this possible?
I found samples of basic routing. But I need to remove the message only after successful processing by http service.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use Camel? Why not just write a simple a JMS client application to do the work?

Comment: Yes. We have already installed instance. And I have an idea to avoid supporting yet another daemon.

Comment: Try to use Camel error handling and manage the errors and you will see the broker redelivers messages on errors.

errorHandler(noErrorHandler());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with Camel.

If you just need to forward the message, the Camel route is very simple.

You can use a [JMS-](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.12.x/jms-component.html) or [ActiveMQ-Consumer](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.12.x/activemq-component.html) to consume messages and either a basic [HTTP producer](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.12.x/http-component.html) or a more specific [REST producer](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.12.x/rest-component.html) to send them to the HTTP endpoint.

If you **configure the consumer to use Broker transactions**, the error part is done almost for free. With broker transactions, Camel automatically commits messages when the processing route had no errors. That means, they are **deleted on the broker**.

If the route has errors (for example an HTTP error on sending) the message is not committed and therefore (instantly) **redelivered by the Broker** and reprocessed by your application.

As roughly described in the comments, you can use an `errorHandler` (basically also a Camel route) to tell Camel what to do in the error case. Typically you have to manage a failure count and move a message after x errors to an error queue for further analysis. Otherwise your processing will be blocked (and busy) by reprocessing a message indefinitely that just fails all the time.